# How to update HDF5 table with partial data?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I'm wondering how one might update an HDF5 table when one only has partial data?  For example, suppose the following df is stored in an HDF5 table.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
         [100,90,80,70,36,45],
         [101,78,65,88,55,78],
         [92,77,42,79,43,32],
         [103,98,76,54,45,65]],
         index = pd.date_range(start='2022-01-01', periods=4)
)

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        (("mkf", "Open"),
         ("mkf", "Close"),
         ("tdf", "Open"),
         ("tdf","Close"),
         ("ghi","Open"),
         ("ghi", "Close"))
)

df
            mkf        tdf        ghi
           Open Close Open Close Open Close
2022-01-01  100    90   80    70   36    45
2022-01-02  101    78   65    88   55    78
2022-01-03   92    77   42    79   43    32
2022-01-04  103    98   76    54   45    65

store = pd.HDFStore('store.h5')
store.append('data', df)
```

Next, suppose I obtain partial data (e.g. data for `mkf` and `tdf` but not `ghi`).

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
        [70,80,90,70],
        [91,68,45,88],
        [92,47,32,79],
        [43,38,77,74]],
        index = pd.date_range(start='2022-01-05', periods=4)
)
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples((("mkf", "Open"),
                   ("mkf", "Close"),
                   ("tdf", "Open"),
                   ("tdf","Close"),
                   )
)    

df1
            mkf        tdf
           Open Close Open Close
2022-01-05   70    80   90    70
2022-01-06   91    68   45    88
2022-01-07   92    47   32    79
2022-01-08   43    38   77    74
```

How can I update `store`?  I tried the following but got a `ValueError`:

```
store.append('data',df1)
 ValueError: cannot match existing table structure for [(mkf, Open),(mkf, Close),(tdf, Open),(tdf, Close),(ghi, Open),(ghi, Close)] on appending data
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in your last statement. You are saving `df` again (not `df1`) with a different key (`df` not `data`). When I modify to `store.append('df',df1)` it creates 2 Tables/keys. However, I don't think that's what you want. When I modify to `store.append('data',df1)` I get the same error as you did. Please clarify your intent. Using `df.to_hdf()` also works with different keys for each dataframe. I think this is a Pandas limitation. I'm 99% sure you can save incomplete data like this if you switch to PyTables (the underlying HDF5 package).

Comment: @kcw78 Good catch, thanks.  I know about PyTables but haven't looked into it yet.  My current work around is to divide the dataframe into a dictionary of sub-dataframes where the keys are the level 0 column indices (i.e. `mkf`, `tdf` and `ghi`).  From there it is pretty natural to populate the `hdf5` table.